# Why does quantities graduated colors shows different data?

Tags: arcmap

I am currently working on a heatmap and trying different ways of visualizing my data. I used unique values in combination with labels which worked fine. 
[image: pic1]
However, it may be to confusing for a research paper and and I decided to use quantities instead. Unfortunately, using the same value I get very strange numbers that are not present in my dataset.
[image: pic2]
[image: pic3]

I haven't used ArcMap in while but this does not seem right to me. Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: Your first result is even stranger, because values look like concatenated decimals.

Comment: I noticed that too, but I seems to work anyway.

Comment: Something to do with local settings. Comma as decimal separator looks suspicious.

Comment: I see why this could be an issue, but "total" is a Double with no seperators.